# Adding non-0 pad to a string to make it 256bits long

Tags: assembly, x86-64, padding

I have a variable sized string in memory, I want to add some "custom" extra bits to make it exactly 256bit long and load it into the ymm1 register, as follows:

```
[ 01100001 01100010 01100011 ...................... ] 
  |________________________| |_____________________|  = 256bits
          24 bits                232 bits pad


add 29bytes (232 bits) pad of the character "A" (0x41H) and load it into ymm1.
```

I tried to fill ymm1 with the custom pad and then load the string into it but with no result. Is there an I64 instruction to do it?

Comment: Does the small string have a constant size?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Thank you for pointing it out, I edited the post accordingly.

Comment: Do you have the length already, or maybe it should be inferred from a terminating zero?

Comment: I don't have the length but the string is zero terminated.

Comment: Also the zero bytes in the ymm1 register, after loading the string, are the only ones that need be replaced with the padding byte.

Comment: Will the bytes that need to be replaced be zero for sure? That would be more convenient than looking for the first zero and then converting that index to a mask (but we can do that too, if necessary)

Comment: I expect the bytes that should be replaced to be only zero since the string is a C-style zero terminated string.

Comment: @asm0: A C-style string may end in a zero byte but be followed by other nonzero bytes. I think harold asked whether the remaining bytes after the (first) zero are zeros too.

Comment: @ecm: I expect the string to contain as zero byte only the terminating zero, I have no info on the bytes after the first zero.

Comment: You can't safely read those bytes after the nul terminator of the string. While it usually "works", the result is possibly undefined. There is the potential for the string to be at or near the end of a page, so that reading those extra bytes spill onto the next page, which can result in a page fault.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: ... Unless you know this buffer isn't near the end of a page.  This is assembly language; it's often possible to ensure that if you control the buffer the string is read into in the first place.  (Of course, in that case probably easiest to just zero 32 bytes and then call whatever reads a zero-terminated string).  But it's also possible to check `(ptr & 4095) < (4096-32)` with MOV / AND / CMP+JCC to make sure it's far enough from the end of a page, and only use the slow strategy if it's not.